# Json array with angularjs not working with ng-repeat directive

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I cannot display all objects from json in html, i get only json array format, but i can display each object when i change url. I would like to display all json objects in html.

First Example

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyPerson', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.person = data;
        });
        });



{% verbatim %}
<body>


<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyPerson">

<div>


{{person}}

</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
{% endverbatim %}



{"meta":{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":3},"objects":[{"city":"Budapest","id":1,"name":"Igor","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/1/","slug":"person"},{"city":"Warszawa","id":2,"name":"Karol","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/2/","slug":"person1"},{"city":"Jerozolima","id":3,"name":"Michal","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/3/","slug":"Ima"}]}
```

So in first example i get all objects from json, but only in json format

Second Example

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyPerson', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/1/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.person = data;
        });
        });




{% verbatim %}
<body>


<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyPerson">

<div>


{{person.name}}
    {{person.city}}
    {{person.id}}

</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
{% endverbatim %}



Igor Budapest 1
```

In second example i change url i type 1 which is id of my object, and then changing my template i get json file in html format which i want.

Third example

```js
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyPerson', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.persons = data;
        });
        });


{% verbatim %}
<body>


<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyPerson">

<div ng-repeat="person in persons">


<p>{{person.name}}</p>
 <p>{{person.city}}</p>
  <p>{{person.id}}</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
{% endverbatim %}
```

In third example i should get all objects, but my html is clear and empty.

I tried everything, I assume that i do everything right in template, mayby the problem is in controller, i should type differently url to jonson?

Comment: i think you want `$scope.persons = data.objects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your url "/people/person/?format=json" returns the following object

```
{"meta":{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":3},
"objects":[{"city":"Budapest","id":1,"name":"Igor","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/1/","slug":"person"},{"city":"Warszawa","id":2,"name":"Karol","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/2/","slug":"person1"},{"city":"Jerozolima","id":3,"name":"Michal","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/3/","slug":"Ima"}]}
```

This object has **only two keys "meta" and "objects"**. So when you use this object in ng-repeat, it cannot find person.name, person.city and person.id since first time it will pick up the "meta" object and next time "objects" object both of which don't have name, city or id.

To correct this, change the success function of get method to assign data.objects to $scope.persons

```
MyApp.controller('MyPerson', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/?format=json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.persons = data.objects;
        });
        });
```

Comment: absolutely no problem :)